# Is it possible to transfer acquired hemophilia with breast milk?

Tags: immunology, hematology, autoimmune

There is a transplacental form of acquired hemophilia: http://www.jpeds.com/article/S0022-3476%2895%2970132-X/abstract

This disease is caused by polyclonal immunoglobulins (IgG1 and IgG4) against the A2 and C2 domains of factor 8. So acquired hemophilia is an autoimmune disease. By the transplacental form the maternal IgG antibodies causing this disease in the newborn. As far as I know IgG antibodies are transferred with breast milk too. Can breast milk cause this disease?

Answer (score 1):

Acquired Hemophilia is an [AutoImmune Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoimmune_disease), hence it is possible to transfer it from mother to child through breastfeeding milk. The antibodies subjected to autoimmune disease also passes into the infant or baby from breastmilk in addition to the healthy antibodies. These abnormal antibodies will act as an [inhibitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_inhibitor) to the enzyme responsible for production of [Factor VIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_VIII) , a blot clotting protein. Less number of factor VIII protein results in increased amount of internal bleeding.

Comment: Thanks James! The question was not about explaining what this disease is. Do you have any proof that it can be transferred to the child with breast milk?